Custom HTML Text Box For Digital Piano Sheet Music
I have tried many methods, and I'm a simple beginner with JavaScript but I want to make a site where I can play a digital piano (without a piano) and have it group keys together that I press at the same time.
For example, if I press "a" then "b" then I press "c" at the same time as "d" it will format it like this: "a b [cd]". I've gotten to the point to where I've failed so many times that I asked ChatGPT, but even it was no help.     I Wasn't Surprised

It's a cool question. I was curious how far I could get in an hour. Let me know if it's of any use to you :D

hello, keyboard events
Here's a minimal proof of concept. Run the demo below -


function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(new Set())
  React.useEffect(() => {
    function onkeydown(event) {
      setState(s => ISet.add(s, event.key))
    }
    function onkeyup(event) {
      setState(s => ISet.delete(s, event.key))
    }
    addEventListener("keyup", onkeyup)
    addEventListener("keydown", onkeydown)
    return () => {
      removeEventListener("keyup", onkeyup)
      removeEventListener("keydown", onkeydown)
    }
  }, [])
  return <div>
    {JSON.stringify(Array.from(state))}
  </div>
}

const ISet = {
  add(t, v) {
    return new Set(t).add(v)
  },
  delete(t, v) {
    const r = new Set(t)
    r.delete(v)
    return r
  }
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>Click here to focus the demo's iframe</li>
  <li>Press any combination of keys on the keyboard</li>
</ol>
<div id="app"></div>



From there, you will want to connect the state changes to WebAudio calls, such as -

playback of piano samples using AudioBufferSourceNode
synthesize audio using OscillatorNode

hello, music to my ears
Expanding on the code above, we make a piano from a QWERTY keyboard layout -
//    W E   T Y U   O P   ]
//   A S D F G H J K L ; '

const piano = new Map(Array.from(
  "awsedftgyhujkolp;']",
  (key, semitone) => [key, semitone]
))

Then a createOsc that computes the frequency for the semitone and plays it -
function createOsc(audioCtx, semitone) {
  const hz = 440 * Math.pow(2, semitone / 12)
  const osc = audioCtx.createOscillator()
  osc.type = "square"
  osc.frequency.setValueAtTime(hz, audioCtx.currentTime)
  osc.connect(audioCtx.destination)
  osc.start();
  return osc
}

Run the snippet below and play your next masterpiece -


function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(new Map())
  const audioCtx = React.useRef(new AudioContext())
  const tuning = React.useRef(-9)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    function onkeydown(e) {
      setState(prev => {
        const osc = prev.get(e.key)
        if (osc != null) return prev
        const semitone = piano.get(e.key)
        if (semitone != null) return IMap.add(
          prev,
          e.key,
          createOsc(audioCtx.current, semitone + tuning.current)
        )
        return prev
      })
    }
    function onkeyup(e) {
      setState(prev => {
        const osc = prev.get(e.key)
        if (osc != null) {
          osc.stop()
          return IMap.delete(prev, e.key)
        }
        return prev
      })
    }
    addEventListener("keyup", onkeyup)
    addEventListener("keydown", onkeydown)
    return () => {
      removeEventListener("keyup", onkeyup)
      removeEventListener("keydown", onkeydown)
    }
  }, [])
  return <div>
    {JSON.stringify(Array.from(state.keys()))}
  </div>
}
 
const piano = new Map(Array.from(
  "awsedftgyhujkolp;']",
  (key, semitone) => [key, semitone]
))

function createOsc(audioCtx, semitone) {
  const hz = 440 * Math.pow(2, semitone / 12)
  const osc = audioCtx.createOscillator()
  osc.type = "square"
  osc.frequency.setValueAtTime(hz, audioCtx.currentTime)
  osc.connect(audioCtx.destination)
  osc.start();
  return osc
}

const IMap = {
  add(t, k, v) {
    return new Map(t).set(k, v)
  },
  delete(t, k) {
    const r = new Map(t)
    r.delete(k)
    return r
  }
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>Click here to focus the demo's iframe</li>
  <li>Play piano on your QWERTY keyboard</li>
</ol>
<pre>
  W E   T Y U   O P   ]
 A S D F G H J K L ; '
</pre>

<div id="app"></div>




A A H F G F S S S U G H G D D D K H U K L F G H F D F G F ' ' '  play it in the demo :D
